# How to insert javascript into echo

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization, timeline

Well i am trying to insert a javascript on php script

```
echo "['". $row['ac']. " ','<span onclick="alert(\'test\')">Click here!</span>',  new Date( ". $row['start']. " ),  new Date( ". $row['end']. " )], ";
```

but i am getting the below error:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or
>   ';' in /home/tregoal/public_html/skai/schedule/index2.php on line 156

i am trying to archive a result as below in order to use it on google charts.

> ['DRIVER ',' 122 ', new Date( 2013,5,01,14,00,00 ), new Date(
>   2013,5,01,15,30,00 )],

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the double-quotes `"` that are used in the `alert span`

```
echo "['". $row['ac']. " ','<span onclick=\"alert(\'test\')\">Click here!</span>',  new Date( ". $row['start']. " ),  new Date( ". $row['end']. " )], ";
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape double quotes `"` in `onClick` event initialization and instead of printing `new Date()` as a plain text concatenate it just like you did it with the variables :

```
echo "['" . $row['ac'] . " ','<span onclick=\"alert('test')\">Click here!</span>', " . new Date( $row['start']) . ", " . new Date($row['end']) . "], ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not escaping properly around `onClick`

Try this

```
echo "['". $row['ac']. " ','<span onclick=\"alert(\'test\')\">Click here!</span>',  new Date( ". $row['start']. " ),  new Date( ". $row['end']. " )], ";
```